# How to loop and call the service asynchronously which should wait at the end for the result in .NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to improve the performance and remove the delay in showing the data to the user on the screen. As per requirement, I need to get the list of the data from a different source, then get the further data from other sources based on the previous data which takes a lot of time and feel that executing them sequentially.

I am looking for the suggestion to improve the performance, asynchronously call the client and wait at the end and reduce the wait time of the request.

```
 foreach (var n in player.data)
        {
            var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.*****.com/buckets/" + **** + "/tests/" + n.id);
            var client1 = new HttpClient();
            request1.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "****-b23a-*****-b1be-********");
            HttpResponseMessage response1 = await client1.SendAsync(request1, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            List<dataroot> root1 = new List<dataroot>();
            if (response1.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    var apiString1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var player1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<envRoot>(apiString1);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(player1.data.environments[0].parent_environment_id))
                    {

                        player.data.Where(x => x.id == player1.data.environments[0].test_id).ToList().ForEach(s => s.isShared = true);
                        player.data.Where(x => x.id == player1.data.environments[0].test_id).ToList().ForEach(s => s.sharedEnvironmentId = player1.data.environments[0].parent_environment_id);
                        //player.data.Where(x=>x.id==player1.data.environments[0].test_id).ToList().ForEach(s=>s.sharedEnvironmentId=player1.data.environments[0].test_id);
                    }

                    player.data.Where(x => x.id == player1.data.environments[0].test_id).ToList().ForEach(s => s.normalenvironmentId = player1.data.environments[0].id);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var test = ex;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: What is included in your question is a code that calls a service and then does nothing with the result (the `player.data.Where(....)` doesn't make any sense on its own as its never used. apart from a local `ForEach`). This makes it challenging to understand what exactly does it mean to *get the further data from other sources*. Also, it's not clear what *call the client* means in this context.

Comment: You may want to look into `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - First , fetch the list of test from source 1 , second - inside for each loop where I am checking whether the test is shared one which means that test has any parent or not. <pre><code>if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(player1.data.environments[0].parent_environment_id)</code></pre>

Comment: Seems like you should send all the IDs in your first request and get all the necessary data back in the response.  (To avoid all these repeated http requests to the 1st api...)

Comment: @WiktorZychla unfortunately, bulk operation is not supported by the Vendor. That is the reason,I am sending a request one by one .

Comment: You probably want to move the async calls out to the browser/client.  ("lazy loading") Your .cs file would return one result at a time.  So multiple async Ajax calls sent via JS, which update the DOM async when they get data returned.  This will at least give the user results as they come in.  Your back-end only needs to return each single request.  (This doesn't necessarily improve performance, but the user won't have to wait for all results to return at once...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the way I did in my sample below:

https://github.com/rajabb/RunningLongRunningTasksEfficientlyAndWaitAtEnd

The main part of code is:

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
      tasks.Add(LongRunningTask.RunAsync(i.ToString()));
 }

 await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```